# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Post has no data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I've struggled with this one for too long, maybe I'm missing something simple.  I've been trying to use an ajax form to avoid reloading the whole page after submitting a form.  Everything is looking fine, and Chrome DevTools is showing a good post holding all of my data.  When I get to my action in the controller, my view model is empty and in its initialized state.  So my though is it has something to do with the way the values are getting mapped to my model on the server side.

This is sort of my code, I was aiming for more than this but I've stripped a lot of it away while trying to trouble shoot.  I feel like this is the most basic possible form of Ajax form post.  I tried making the names and variables generic to try and simplify, so if something don't add up that might be why.

Please help I'm going crazy.

View:

```
@model EmiExpress.Web.Areas.Reports.Models.TurnkeyLiability.AddNewReportFormVm
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewReport", "Reports",
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" } ))
{

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GroupId)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DevExpress().CheckBoxFor(
            model => model.Save, 
            s =>
            {
                s.Text = "Save Values?";
            }
            ).GetHtml()
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
    </div>
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewReport(AddNewReportFormVm viewModel)
        {
            int x = 5;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                x = 10; //just some junk while I try to get this working
            }

            return PartialView("Controls/_cbpReportRunLoading", x);
        }
```

Model:

```
public class AddNewReportFormVm
    {
        public AddNewReportFormVm()
        {
            GroupId = "";
            Save = false;
        }


        [Required]
        public string GroupId{ get; private set; }

        public bool Save{get; set;}
    }
```

Network Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1130
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 02:41:05 GMT
Persistent-Auth: true
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcc3RlZmFudG91YmlhXHNvdXJjZVxyZXBvc1xFbWlFeHByZXNzXEVtaUV4cHJlc3MuV2ViXFJlcG9ydHNcVHVybmtleUxpYWJpbGl0eVxSdW5OZXdSZXBvcnQ=?=
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2300
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DXCss: 0_2312,1_50,1_53,1_51,0_2317,1_40,1_17,0_2214,1_16,0_2219,0_2221,0_2225,1_18,1_4,0_2257,18_3,18_11,18_7,0_2261,0_2313,1_34,0_2273,16_3,16_11,16_7,0_2277,1_44,0_2192,24_359,24_364,24_360,1_20,9_12,9_15,0_2338,9_1,0_2342,9_4,1_7,15_0,15_4,/Content/Site.css,/Areas/Reports/Content/TurnkeyLiability.css
DXScript: 1_228,1_226,1_227,1_225,1_304,1_211,1_185,1_221,1_188,1_182,1_280,1_293,1_271,1_287,1_290,1_184,17_42,17_3,1_286,1_189,17_8,1_298,1_193,17_10,1_288,1_195,1_194,17_11,1_209,1_217,1_296,1_279,1_302,1_254,1_235,1_247,1_303,1_222,17_12,1_297,17_41,1_190,1_223,1_291,1_289,1_196,1_256,1_263,1_262,1_255,1_252,1_259,1_253,1_261,1_258,1_257,1_248,1_244,1_242,1_251,1_250,1_249,1_246,1_245,1_260,1_241,1_238,1_239,1_240,1_243,17_15,17_17,1_272,1_273,17_19,1_274,1_275,17_20,17_21,1_224,17_14,1_277,17_24,17_28,1_281,17_25,1_294,17_27,1_292,1_295,17_32,1_299,17_36,17_40,1_192,1_285,18_36,18_38,18_33,18_42,18_37,18_35,17_31,1_208,1_206,1_212,1_201,1_215,1_203,1_205,1_204,1_284,1_198,1_213,17_1,1_197,17_0,1_199,17_2,1_200,17_4,1_202,1_219,17_7,17_23,1_207,17_9,1_276,1_216,17_22,1_214,1_218,17_38,1_220,16_52,16_152,16_47,16_36,16_153,16_28,16_27,16_48,16_50,16_32,16_41,16_159,16_154,16_34,16_51,16_54,16_40,16_158,16_43,16_44,16_33,16_162,16_46,16_45,16_55,16_49,16_31,16_38,16_37,16_39,16_53,16_42,16_26,16_29,16_30,17_35,16_160,16_35,10_11,10_10,10_12,10_13,10_14,17_6,1_236,17_16,1_229,24_401,24_400,24_402,24_403,24_406,24_407,24_408,24_404,24_405,1_230,24_379,24_380,9_45,9_36,24_388,24_398,9_38,9_37,17_30,9_46,17_44,9_42,9_39,9_31,17_29,9_41,9_32,9_44,9_43,9_40,15_16,15_14,15_10,15_11,15_13,20_0,1_237,9_48,9_47
Host: localhost:57144
Origin: http://localhost:57144
Referer: http://localhost:57144/Reports/TurnkeyLiability
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Form Data:

```
GroupId: abc
Save: C
DXScript: 1_228,1_226,1_227,1_225,1_304,1_211,1_185,1_221,1_188,1_182,1_280,1_293,1_271,1_287,1_290,1_184,17_42,17_3,1_286,1_189,17_8,1_298,1_193,17_10,1_288,1_195,1_194,17_11,1_209,1_217,1_296,1_279,1_302,1_254,1_235,1_247,1_303,1_222,17_12,1_297,17_41,1_190,1_223,1_291,1_289,1_196,1_256,1_263,1_262,1_255,1_252,1_259,1_253,1_261,1_258,1_257,1_248,1_244,1_242,1_251,1_250,1_249,1_246,1_245,1_260,1_241,1_238,1_239,1_240,1_243,17_15,17_17,1_272,1_273,17_19,1_274,1_275,17_20,17_21,1_224,17_14,1_277,17_24,17_28,1_281,17_25,1_294,17_27,1_292,1_295,17_32,1_299,17_36,17_40,1_192,1_285,18_36,18_38,18_33,18_42,18_37,18_35,17_31,1_208,1_206,1_212,1_201,1_215,1_203,1_205,1_204,1_284,1_198,1_213,17_1,1_197,17_0,1_199,17_2,1_200,17_4,1_202,1_219,17_7,17_23,1_207,17_9,1_276,1_216,17_22,1_214,1_218,17_38,1_220,16_52,16_152,16_47,16_36,16_153,16_28,16_27,16_48,16_50,16_32,16_41,16_159,16_154,16_34,16_51,16_54,16_40,16_158,16_43,16_44,16_33,16_162,16_46,16_45,16_55,16_49,16_31,16_38,16_37,16_39,16_53,16_42,16_26,16_29,16_30,17_35,16_160,16_35,10_11,10_10,10_12,10_13,10_14,17_6,1_236,17_16,1_229,24_401,24_400,24_402,24_403,24_406,24_407,24_408,24_404,24_405,1_230,24_379,24_380,9_45,9_36,24_388,24_398,9_38,9_37,17_30,9_46,17_44,9_42,9_39,9_31,17_29,9_41,9_32,9_44,9_43,9_40,15_16,15_14,15_10,15_11,15_13,20_0,1_237,9_48,9_47
DXCss: 0_2312,1_50,1_53,1_51,0_2317,1_40,1_17,0_2214,1_16,0_2219,0_2221,0_2225,1_18,1_4,0_2257,18_3,18_11,18_7,0_2261,0_2313,1_34,0_2273,16_3,16_11,16_7,0_2277,1_44,0_2192,24_359,24_364,24_360,1_20,9_12,9_15,0_2338,9_1,0_2342,9_4,1_7,15_0,15_4,/Content/Site.css,/Areas/Reports/Content/TurnkeyLiability.css
DXMVCEditorsValues: {"Save":true}
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: The only parameter in your POST method is `HttpPostedFile file` (and you do not have a file input in the view). The method would need to be `public ActionResult NewReport(AddNewReportFormVm model)` to bind to your model

Comment: And `GroupId` will never bind because you have a `private` setter

Comment: @StephenMuecke My mistake, I was trouble shooting and forgot to put it back to normal.  Also, I am actually using the GroupId as a hidden field and setting it in the model constructor, but was testing it as a text box and getting the same results.

Comment: Remove `private` from the `set` for `GroupId`, and that will bind fine. But there is something odd about your `Save` data - its posting `C` instead of `true` or `false`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, and when it is unchecked the value is "U".  I'm new to web dev so I am not familiar with the norms

Comment: I do not use DevExpress, so I cannot comment on that (but using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Save)` will work fine

Comment: @StephenMuecke holy crap stephen that was it.  Thank you so much!  But why??  My thought behind making these fields private was that I didn't want the user to set those fields since I would be setting them in the constructor.  My guess is that now when the controller receives the post request, it is unable to rebuild the model based on the provided data.  So given that, is there an appropriate way to protect these fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172922/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-erpaderp).